# How to do a nested loop over different time frames in a pandas time series?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

> I have got a pandas time series with minutely data over multiple days. I would like to loop over the times series that consists of a single day of data, and for each such loop over the minutely data. Is that possible and how?

I know of the .iterrows() method, so to loop over a single day I can manage.

EDIT: The data may look something as follows

```
dti = pd.date_range('2018-01-01', '2018-01-08', freq='min')
n = len(dti)

x = np.random.randn(n)
y = np.random.randn(n)
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y': y}, index=dti)

# we haven't got data from say 00:00 to 00:06
for i in range(1,9):
    df.loc[f'2018-01-0{i}  00:00:00':f'2018-01-0{i} 06:00:00', 'x'] = np.nan
    df.loc[f'2018-01-0{i}  00:00:00':f'2018-01-0{i} 06:00:00', 'y'] = np.nan

df.dropna()
```

Then for each day, `df.loc['2018-01-01']`, `df.loc['2018-01-03']` etc I would like to take the first 50 observations, do some calculation [to be precise, in this case I want to perform a linear regression between the 50 observations of the two columns and store the "slope" coefficient] and put the result in a new column on the 50:th row for the corresponding day in `df`, then take observation 2 to 51, do the same calculation and put the result in the 51:th row for the corresponding day in `df`, etc. This is the best explanation I can give!

Much grateful for any help provided!

Comment: please show an example of your daatframe and your expected output

Comment: Looping, while possible, should be pushed down your list of options in favour of another (better) method if available.  Have a look at this to see better options: https://engineering.upside.com/a-beginners-guide-to-optimizing-pandas-code-for-speed-c09ef2c6a4d6

Comment: @ansev I expanded a little, but I cannot really write more of the expected output since that would mean I have to solve my own question!